# Excel match(less than) function behaves inconsistently

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, excel-2010

When I put a date at the first date location, I wish match(less than) function will return me the location of the rightmost match date on the same row.  (I understand it will not be recommended to put the search date on the same row)

For row 3:3, it does what I want.  I get location 10.
But for row 4:4, it returned me my search date location instead of the date in the date array.
The only difference between the two rows is the search date cell on 4:4 is beyond column G.

I could not explain why.  I wish I just miss some known fact.  I hope/expect Excel behaves consistently!  Thanks for any advice.

[image: Excel Match issue explanation]

Comment: To use match_type 1 then the data in the lookup array must be in ascending order, otherwise results cannot be guaranteed to be correct - by having the lookup values (G3 and H4) within the data you have created a series of data that isn't in ascending order, hence inconsistent results

Comment: Deleted my earlier comment - missed the match type = 1...

Comment: Thanks barry, I understand that.   Maybe this question is not a question because I am not using match properly and match will not work properly too.  But I wish I could know the mystery of match that why it behaves differently dependent on where the lookup value is.

Comment: It's not a mystery - barry explained it...

Comment: If match(less than) behaves consistently, either match should return the lookup value location, OR the location of the matched date in date array.  It is the mystery.  Maybe there is no point to discuss further because the usage is not correct, but I just want to understand the difference in the result.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer but I can't comment yet. I don't think Barry has quite answered the question. According to the [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835873.aspx) MATCH returns the position of the matched value within lookup_array, not the value itself.  Also notice if you recreate the OP's scenario and then move lookup value for the second MATCH function one cell over to the left (G4) it returns the result he's looking for.

[image]